# Edititing main page in Shopware

Tags: shopware

I´m usind Shopware to create a website ( www.futureindustries.co ) I need to change all of the pictures that are on the main page (the slider). Actually there is first slide blank and then 2 pictures. I need to change the first picture (blank) but I have no idea where to find the style sheet or that piece of code where I ľill put the path to the picture. I mean that I have no idea where to find place where I would change this:

```
background-image: url("");
```

To this:

```
background-image: url("path to the image I want");
```

I´m using theme "Views"

I know that this may be very irrelevant for most of you (maybe all of you) but I´m really desperate. I feel like I´ve opened every file and i still can´t find it.

To make it clear - I am repairing the website and the programmer that created this site is not responding to anyone so I can´t ask him how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The content seems exist in database. You can find & edit it from `Backend menu > Marketing > Shopping Worlds > Startseite`.